# User inputs math equation

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a program which takes a math equation given by the user and draws a graph (function) of the equation.

The problem is due to security concerns I cannot pass the initial equation onto the computer (ie. I needed to write my own program that breaks the equation down, brackets and all, and individually write each divide, multiply, add, and subtract in that equation).

This process takes a great deal of time and therefore makes my program 'too slow'.

Does anyone know of a way around this?

I am using Flash Pro CS5.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your implementation, I don't see any reason for this to be slow.

Answer (score 2):

You might find this helpful:
http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?251592-Equation-Parser